# Automatic Birthday Notification on User's Birth Date

Tags: wordpress, plugins, automation, code-snippets

I have a WordPress and BuddyPress website. And I want to be able to send a Birthday Greeting to my users on the day of their Birthday.

I have this Code:

```
    // Add this code to your theme's functions.php file or use a custom code plugin

function wbcom_send_birthday_reminders() {
    // Get all BuddyPress members
    $bp_members = new BP_User_Query(array('per_page' => -1));

    if (!empty($bp_members->results)) {
        foreach ($bp_members->results as $member) {
            // Get the user's birthday from xProfile field
            $birthday = bp_get_profile_field_data(array('field' => 'Birthday', 'user_id' => $member->ID));

            // Check if it's the user's birthday
            if ($birthday && date('md', strtotime($birthday)) == date('md')) {
                // It's the user's birthday, send a reminder email
                $to = $member->user_email;
                $subject = 'Happy Birthday!';
                $message = 'Dear ' . $member->display_name . ',\n\nHappy Birthday!';

                // Send email
                wp_mail($to, $subject, $message);
            }
        }
    }
}

// Schedule the birthday reminder to be sent daily
add_action('init', function () {
    if (!wp_next_scheduled('wbcom_send_birthday_reminders')) {
        wp_schedule_event(time(), 'daily', 'wbcom_send_birthday_reminders');
    }
});

// Hook the function to the scheduled event
add_action('wbcom_send_birthday_reminders', 'wbcom_send_birthday_reminders');
```

Now, I was informed that this code will not scale--because it searches All Users, instead of searching daily for users whose Birthday falls under the current Month and current day.

How do I update this code to function as such?

2.) How do I get this code to send the Birthday Notification by 6am in the Morning, on the day of the user's Birthday?

Regards.

Comment: Hi. Questions on Stack Overflow should show evidence of: 1. research, 2. attempted solution, 3. code (if a coding problem), 4. why attempt(s) failed and 5. desired outcome. Your question only shows #5. Are you able to make an attempt? If not, as is, the question is too broad, doesn't help us know what you currently understand about WordPress development, and doesn't help us know how we could best help you. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and why your question is at [risk of down-votes](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/).